# Optimization of java code for reducing complexity

Tags: java, optimization, java-8, libraries

I am actually new to java libraries. I dont know what this code is doing.
I have been given a task to optimize this. Any help will be useful.

I mean to ask whether `str.equals(local)` checks for entire string aur for particular index value in the `for` loop.

```
public void fnc(String str, int[] ar1)
    {
        String local = "findnumber";
        for(int i=0; i<ar1.length; i++)
        {
            if(str.equals(local) && ar1[i] * 2 > 10) 
            {
                Integer ip = new Integer(ar1[i]);
                ip = ip * 2;
                System.out.print(ip.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show your attempts. There's lots of easy things to improve in here, but there's little learning advantage for you in just telling you the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by complexity?  Computational complexity of the algorithm?  Complexity in terms of humans reading / understanding the code?

Comment: "whether str.equals(local) checks for entire string aur for particular index value" Nope, it just checks whether `str` equals `local`. Nothing to do with the loop index.

Comment: complexity of the algorithm as a whole @StephenC

Comment: @AndyTurner i have placed the **str.equals(local)** condition above the loop body.

Comment: `if(str.equals("findnumber")) for(int i: ar1) { i*=2; if(i>10) System.out.print(i); }`

Comment: do you think  replacing 
`ip = ip * 2;
 System.out.print(ip.toString());`    
with  
`System.out.print(ip * 2.toString());`
 will be useful??

Comment: There is no need to do the multiplication twice. Since its result is needed for the comparison, you have to do it before the comparison. You can call `toString()` on an object only (like an `Integer` instance), but that’s obsolete here, as [`print(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-int-) will already do the intended action.

Comment: *"complexity of the algorithm as a whole"* - that does NOT answer my question.  The question was ... what do you mean by complexity.  Your answer is "circular".

Comment: Like if I asked you "What do you mean by a cat?  A feline or a piece of earthmoving equipment?"  ... and you answered "I mean the whole cat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big O complexity of the algorithm is `O(N)` where `N` is the array size.  You cannot improve on that ... for the arguments provided and producing the same output.

There are some things that can be done to improve efficiency though.

- Hint: look for a computation that is performed on each loop iteration that could be performed once.
- Hint: look for some unnecessary object creation<sup>1</sup>
- Hint: unnecessary *use* of a reference type.

There are one or two other *questionable* micro-optimizations, but see if you can spot them without any hints.  (I say "questionable" because I suspect that the JIT compiler would do the same optimization itself.)

One final note: the actual speed of the code will be dominated by the `print` statement, and its ability of the OS to write stuff to (for example) the console.   And probably by JVM startup / warmup effects ... unless the `fnc` method is called many times.

---

<sup>1 - Notwithstanding anything else, `new Integer(...)` is the wrong way to convert an `int` to an `Integer`.</sup>

Comment: Everything you can do with this simple loop falls into the micro-optimization category of that “the JIT can do that” sort. As long as they are also removing unnecessary repetition or obsolete processing steps, in other words, also remove visual clutter from the source code, there is nothing wrong with that. Micro-optimization is bad only, when the code readability suffers from it or too many development time is spent on it…

Comment: can i ask though what does 
`Integer ip = new Integer(ar1[i]);` 
doing here is it converting an integer element to integer again.

Comment: @Holger - If you explicitly `new` an object, it is doubtful that the JIT compiler will optimize that away.

Comment: @Sandeep - No.  It is converting an `int` to an `Integer`,  But do you need to convert to an `Integer`?

Comment: @Stephen C: it does, if Escape Analysis can prove its pure local nature, which is the case here. Of course, using `Integer.valueOf` (or just autoboxing) to denote the irrelevance of the object identity explicitly is still better. However, as you already stated, the printing operation will dominate the speed, so it may be the case that the JIT doesn’t look at this loop…

Comment: @Holger - yes, but is escape analysis enabled by default?  I thought not .....

Comment: @StephenC I was given only these lines of code with task of optimization. I don't know what actually this function is used for

Comment: @Stephen C: [Escape analysis is supported and enabled by default in Java SE 6u23 and later](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis)…

Comment: @Sandeep - that is not relevant.  You can tell what the type of `arr` is from the method signature!

Comment: @StephenC @Holger thank you, the answer was helpful.. Specially the conversion of `int`to `Integer`

Comment: @StephenC how can one tell `arr` from method signature.. sorry if that too basic question

Comment: @Holger - didn't know that.  But even so, it is unclear that the JIT can figure out that the code can be rewritten to use an `int`.  The transformation entails replacing non-static `Integer.toString()` with static `Integer.toString(int)`.  That's a big ask for a non-sentient optimizer.

Comment: @Sandeep - sorry `ar1`.  But the answer is **by reading it**.  What is the type of `ar1`?  What does the method declaration say?  And what does that mean the type of `ar1[i]` is???

Comment: @StephenC the method is performing very simple task of checking whether input string to method is "findnumber" if it is than print those element of array which when multiplied by 2 is greater than 10. The question is isn't converting `int`to `Integer` irrelevant

Comment: But the CODE >>is<< converting an `int` to an `Integer`.  And converting an `int` to an `Integer` when you don't need to is something that can be optimized!!   So it is totally relevant.

Comment: But I'm not going to spend any more time of this.  You have had enough of my time.

Comment: so i can actually remove the line `Integer ip = new Integer(ar1[i]);` and directly write  System.out.print(ar1[i]*2);   it will be fine know??

Comment: @StephenC THANK YOU really

Comment: @Holger escape analysis is just that - *analysis* of the scope of an object. After it, there could be many things happening like *biased-locking*, *scalar replacement*. The thing is this has to hit `C2` compiler to be even analyzed with escape analysis and that `might` not happen at all.

Comment: @Eugene: that’s what I already said, [the printing operation will dominate the speed, so it may be the case that the JIT doesn’t look at this loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629876/optimization-of-java-code-for-reducing-complexity/44630095?noredirect=1#comment76246291_44630095)…

Comment: @Holger I don't know why but I sort of thought your hint was something like, don't worry about it - the JIT will take care; from the first comment. I guess that was not your intention...